# Nested for loop Integer comparison - Unexpected index

Tags: java, arraylist, nested

I am capturing user input in the form of a series of integers, this happens twice, stored in 2 ArrayLists. Here is my code for that:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  System.out.println("Enter the first set of integers on one line, end with -1.");
  Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  int item = 0;
  while (
     item != -1
  ) {
     item = scanner1.nextInt();
     list1.add(item);
  }
  //remove the last item on arraylist because its the -1
  list1.remove(list1.size()-1);
  //done making list1
  //start list2
  item = 0;
  ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  System.out.println("Enter the first set of integers on one line, end with -1.");
  Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (
     item != -1
  ) {
     item = scanner2.nextInt();
     list2.add(item);
  }
  //remove the last item on arraylist because its the -1
  list2.remove(list2.size()-1);
  //end list2
```

My problem occurs when I attempt to create a `list3` made from the duplicates of `list1` and `list2`. I do this by taking **each**(first for loop level) Integer from the first list, and compare it to each(second for loop nesting) of the Integers from the second list. 
Should they match, they are added to the third list as such,

```
  ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){//list1
     for(int j=0;j<list2.size();j++){//list2
        if(list1.get(i) == list2.get(j)){//check if same 
           int value = list1.get(i);
           list3.add(value);
        }
     }//for list 2
  }//for list 1
```

Say I ran the program, gave some input, and printed the list variables:

```
[10, 200, 6, 99, 3, 5, 90, 44]
[200, 56, 34, 3, 5, 87, 44, 5]
```

After all this, why is does the printline statement for `list3` give me: `[3, 5, 5, 44]`

Why is the 200 ignored? Do I not understand something about the index? About the looping? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, `Integer` are objects, not primitives.
So, instead of:

```
if(list1.get(i) == list2.get(j))
```

use:

```
if(list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(j)))
```

For instance:

```
Integer i = 42;
Integer j = 42;
boolean b = i == j;
```

In there, `b` will be `true`. But this is only true for integers between -128 and 127 because Java cache those values.